# Third-party apps are dark in desktop panel

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, 22.04, top-bar

Third-party apps are dark in the notification area of the Ubuntu 22.04 desktop panel.

[image: here]

Normally the Discord logo should appear there, moreover not only Discord but all third-party application icons look like this.

I rebooted the system, changed themes, and disabled plugins, but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: I solved the problem using Ubuntu AppIndicators.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Ubuntu AppIndicators GNOME shell extension from the Extensions app (gnome-shell-extensions) as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]